# How to Correctly Separate Dao Class from Business Logic Class?

Tags: android, model, dao, abstraction, greendao

I'm using GreenDao to handle my Dao on Android. GreenDao uses a Java Application to generate all Dao classes automatically. As such, you don't want to modify the classes as your custom code will be overwritten on the next run of the Java App.

This is my current approach to separation, it seems close, but very redundant:

Dao Model (automatically generated):

```
public class Car() {
  ...
  String mMake;
  String mModel;
  int mMilesDriven;
  ...

  public String getMake() {
    return mMake;
  }

  public String getModel() {  
    return mModel;  
  }

  public int getMilesDriven() {    
    return mMilesDriven;  
  }

}
```

Business Logic Class:

```
public class CarUtil() {

  Car mCar;

  public CarUtil(Car car) {
    mCar = car;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return mCar.getMake() + " " + mCar.getModel();
  }

  public int getMilesDriven() {
    return mCar.getMilesDriven();
  }

}
```

Obviously this looks horribly redundant, however, since Car() is auto generated and can't have the correct business logic (such as combining the make and model for the car's name), I think it's necessary redundancy?

I believe my models achieve good abstraction of the data layer and the business logic layer, but how can I make it more efficient as in less code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your business logic into the `KEEP-SECTION`-blocks. These won't get overwritten. (You have to tell the greendao generator to use `KEEP-SECTIONS`.)

If you don't want to expose some generated `public`methods you can also have an interface on your generated class which only exposes the things you want and work with that interface in your application.

**UPDATE**

Interface:

```
public interface CarUtil {
    String getName();
    int getMilesDriven();
}
```

Entity (generated);

```
public class Car() implements CarUtil {

    ...
    String mMake;
    String mModel;
    int mMilesDriven;
    ...

    public String getMake() {
        return mMake;
    }

    public String getModel() {  
        return mModel;  
    }

    public int getMilesDriven() {    
        return mMilesDriven;  
    }

    // KEEP-SECTION-START
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return getMake() + " " + getModel();
    }
}
```

So normally you just use the interface and so the interface and so the other public methods are hidden.

Depending on your needs it might be best to wrap the generated DAO (not the entity) so that only the DAO-layer knows about the real implementation.

Comment: I'd like to avoid KEEP-SECTION, and I also want separation of these layers.

This being said, I can't put any code into the Dao, therefore, I couldn't use an interface either. 

If that's the case, am I doing the best possible with the above?

Thank you!

Comment: @AutoM8R Including business logic into your Entity classes follows a domain-driven design, which gets enforced by the interface, which hides unwanted methods. Another point is performance: creating two objects for every data-row may slow you down, since instantiation may still be expensive. So I think you should rethink, if you want to use KEEP-SECTION.

Comment: thank you. I will reconsider, I can't quite see how the interface will cut down on code, as the interface will need the same methods as my business logic class. An example would be great, but I don't expect anymore of your time.

Comment: @AutoM8R See my edit, if you have furrther remarks or questions just leave a comment... ;)

Comment: Thanks! You're very kind. I suppose I'll have to remember to put the implements CarUtil back in after each DaoGenerator run, but I can manage that!

Comment: @AutoM8R There's a method on the entity in your dao-generator project. Can't remember the signature right now, but I think it accepts a String[] contain all interface names your entity has to implement. By the way: Take care, that your additional includes go into the corresponding KEEP-SECTION or use canonical class names.

Comment: Thanks again kind sir